# Ionic getting to know what was the recently run apps on android

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm writing a simple android app detection using Ionic (fairly new too as well with mobile apps dev using Ionic). Using this plugin [App Availaibility](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/app-availability) I was able to get a list of installed apps, however is there a way or plugin or is it possible to know what was the recent app that was used in the foreground? Like if a com.android.appname was run, it may be able to detect it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No there is not, I'd assume that there won't be a plugin for this either. In order for the device to know what app has ran in the past, it must hold this data somewhere. I doubt google or apple does anything like this.

or

you can always try and build a plugin yourself and see if its possible.